# .each(function()) not looping at loading page but yes a refreshing with dedicated button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been making a page to load a list of tasks from a database, it works fine.

I've been asked to add a title on hover to check description without having to click on a task, for easy management.

I've done that by looping each `tr` in a table and adding the title with `.attr('title','test');`.

This is the code:

```
console.log("runs?");
that.tableSalidas.row(this).$('tr').each(function(){
    data =  that.tableSalidas.row(this).data();
    $(this).attr('title', data.observaciones);
    console.log("Working..");
});
console.log("yes...");
```

The console only prints out:

```
runs?
yes...
```

Only after I hit a reload button I have, or a timer I have set up calls on the api again, the title will be added and the console.log i have in the loop logs...

```
runs?
(3) Working..
yes...
```

adding the titles too...

[image: Title working]

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Give us more code/context. It is very probable that the code runs before your datatable is populated.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by *"hit a reload button I have, or a timer I have set up calls on the api again"*?  Are you executing this code twice, and modifying the DOM between those two executions?  When this code first executes, are there any table rows?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: So, once the page is loaded, the user can hit a refresh button to get more tasks from the BBDD. There is a timer of a minute that "hits" that button.
@ZoliSzabó says that is probable that the code runs before datatable is populated, I think that's correct, how do I wait for population of datatable to run that loop?

Comment: Sorry, i cant make a fiddle of some sort... I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in a previous comment, the code block seems to be executed *before* the datatable gets filled with data. So it needs to be delayed to when it is guaranteed that the data is there.
Check out the `init` event: https://datatables.net/reference/event/init

Something like the following should work:

```
that.tableSalidas.on('init', function () {
    console.log("runs?");
    that.tableSalidas.row(this).$('tr').each(function(){
        data =  that.tableSalidas.row(this).data();
        $(this).attr('title', data.observaciones);
        console.log("Working..");
    });
    console.log("yes...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This was the fix!